# How to declare a Global variable inside any function in 'C'?

Tags: arrays, c, variables, scope, global

I want to declare a global variable inside a main() function...

Below is what I want the program to act like

```
#include<stdio.h>
int a[6];
int main()
{
  int n;
  scanf("%d",&n);
}
```

I want to create an array of user given size (here n-size) and I want to access that array globally.
So instead of creating array of size '6' outside the main() function, I want to create array of 'n' size globally instead of passing array whenever function is called...

Comment: This is the exact use-case for dynamic memory allocation scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use an array allocated into the heap by using `malloc`

```
#include<stdio.h>
int *a;
int main()
{
  int n;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  a = malloc(sizeof(*a) * n);
  if(a == NULL) {
      // malloc error
  }

  // use your array here

  free(a); // at the end of the program make sure to release the memory allocated before
}
```

Comment: what if we use "extern" keyword?

Comment: the `extern` keyword is used when you work with multiple files, but this is not the case

Answer (score 5):

You can declare a pointer as global variable and assign buffer to that in `main()`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int *a;
int main()
{
  int n;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  a = calloc(n, sizeof(*a)); /* calloc() initializes the allocated buffer to zero */
  if (a == NULL)
  {
    /* calloc() failed, handle error (print error message, exit program, etc.) */
  }
}
```

Comment: can't we use "extern" keyword?\

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that.

The closest you can get it, define a pointer in file scope (i.e., global), allocate memory to it by using allocator function (`malloc()` and family) and use the same pointer in other function calls as necessary. As the lifetime of the allocated memory is until deallocated programmatically (passed to `free()`), other functions can make use of the allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int *a;
int main()
{
  int n;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  a = malloc(n*sizeof(*a));
  free(a); // Need to free memory space
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can anyone suggest me how to improve my answer skill better in stack overflow?

Comment: For one thing you can add a better explanation and address the question.